# Is test driven development a form of unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Our company is in the process of improving the code quality and processes to adopt when delivering a piece of code. My question is concerned to unit testing and I wanted to gather information on the processes you adopt when you are asked to implement a functionality.

Is TDD a form of unit test. From what i understand in TDD, you write your test first (which fails), write your code and then run your test which should pass. It may be that the code will make external method call. But how are we suppose to know about the stubbing required when we are writing our test first?

When you are building your application prior release, what kind of test do you include in the build? Does the build run your integration test or does it run only your unit test?

Apart from TDD, do you write any other kind of test. Sorry if the question are slightly distorted. Your experience on how you undertake development is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'd say 'yes; TDD is a form of unit testing'.

Comment: Having a look at the following [post](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/11/tdd-tests-are-not-unit-tests.aspx), I am left confused as to whether we should write additional test, other that the TDD test we are writing?

Comment: It depends on your testing systems.  We write extra tests and eventually the TDD tests fall by the wayside (where 'eventually' happens rather to soon, on average).  The extra tests are bigger, using the whole system rather than unit-test oriented.  This is in large part a case of inherited mind-set.  Although unit tests are important, you still need to test a bigger scales than just the unit; the customers will be testing the integrated system, and while the unit tests make it more probable that the integration will be smooth, the integration must still be tested.

Comment: When you write those extra test, do you still mock results from dependencies in your code, or is that a full-fledged integration test, invoking database call and stuff?
I tend write test that invoke my entry point of my class, mock dependency results and assert whether the end result of the exit point of that class is what I expected. Is that a good practice?
I also have integration test in my project that invoke DB.

Comment: The stuff I'm testing _is_ the DBMS; you can't test a DBMS by mocking out the DBMS!  So, the next level is basically integration and functional testing, where there's limited difference between the two.  One of the (very big) problems we face is that the code is up to 30 years old, and was not written with unit testing, and it is difficult to get unit tests to work because of the enormous infrastructure behind the system.

Answer (score 6):

TDD can be a whole lot more than Unit Testing - so I'd say that Unit Testing is just a part of TDD. The methodology as a whole I think can include creating tests (expressing expectation/requirement of correct behaviour) on the result of any process in the software development. Be that writing code, build scripts, deployment scripts, database scripts, data import/export/transformation... whatever you need to do you should ask yourself, "How can I prove this has worked? Can I automate a test for that?"

As an example: something that is often overlooked because it falls out of scope of Unit Testing but is a very valid test, and one that is important to front-load in the development process is deployment.

If a software development cannot be easily deployed to the production environment without significant effort and change (to the software or environment architecture) it is important to know this up front, rather than a week before it has to go live. Once you have that process nailed, wouldn't it be nice to have a way of testing to make sure that it was correctly deployed?

When you understand that process - why not script and automate it? If you know the requirement is that it must be deployed, why not write a test for that before even doing it?

I've said it before but I'll say it again - the best resource I've found on the subject is **Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests** - which is part of the Kent Beck Signature Series.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll have a look at the book. I have not yet been doing TDD in my project, but along the line, I have written unit test in a traditional way that check all possible path of a method to be sure that any further change does not cause regression.

Answer (score 3):

[TDD is not about testing](http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/11/21/tdd-is-not-about-testing/).  TDD *uses* tests to drive the design of your code.  TDD *produces* tests as a happy side-effect of designing your code by writing the tests first, but it's not about testing: it isn't a testing methodology and the purpose is not to produce tests.

> Is test driven development a form of unit testing?

No.  It is a *design* methodology.

> From what I understand in TDD, you write your test first (which
>   fails), write your code and then run your test which should pass.

You're missing a very important step.  You write your test first, you write your code until your test passes - and then you **refactor**.  The tests permit you to refactor *safely*, ensuring that the desired behavior continues to work while you adjust your design.  The tests also guide you to *testable* code, promoting smaller methods, shorter parameter lists, and overall much simpler design than other methodologies lead you to.

> Apart from TDD, do you write any other kind of test?

When I do, it's usually a sign that I've failed to do TDD properly (but it certainly happens).  We have both unit tests and user acceptance tests; both can be written prior to code, but sometimes our user acceptance tests are written later in the development cycle.  They shouldn't be, but sometimes they are.

Comment: Thanks Carl. Suppose I have a requirement to implement. I will first break down the requirements into cases. For each case I'll write a(or more) test and then I will write the code to fulfill the test(s). Run the test and see that it passes, mean that the code is OK. Now refactor. This process, I understand, allow me to structure and design my code based on the test I wrote.. But in a nutshell, I am writing test(s) to test a case. Although its call TDD, isn't the test being written in TDD testing each case, i.e testing each unit of code although the code is written last?

Comment: [When I do, it's usually a sign that I've failed to do TDD properly]
Of all the tests I wrote in TDD, those tests only verify each case of my requirement. But I will have to have test that verify whether each case of requirement works well with each other so that the overall requirement is satisfied. How do you cater for that?

Comment: Either the individual requirements work correctly together (you should strive for this), or they don't.  If they don't, that's missing functionality - an unfilled requirement - write a test for it, and make it pass.  That's definitely test-driving.

Answer (score 2):

You have several questions here, ill try to address them in a logical order

**Is TDD a form of unit testing?**

Id say "yes", in the sense it creates unit tests, even if it isnt the only benefit of using TDD. On the topic stressed by commentators, but not mentioned in your question: TDD not only ensures test coverage and documentiation (good tests are one of the best form of low level code documentation). Using TDD forces you to make certain design decisions, usually improving the overall app design.

**Do You write other tests?**

Well, I don't write any other unit tests. The point of TDD is the development of the code parallel to the development of the tests. By writing software in a cycle - single test, only enough code to pass it, you're sure that your tests document all the functionality and behaviour you require from your code and you make sure that the code is testable (you have to write it that way doing TDD). There should be no need for additional unit tests

There are other kinds of tests that you should use tho. Integration tests come to mind first, but there are other, like acceptance tests. If you have those automated, you will have it easier on you. Its not you who should be writing acceptance tests - it should be your customer/stakeholder, and You should be helping him on the technical part of writing them. You may be interested in Fitnesse http://fitnesse.org/ - its a tool that helps non-technical people build acceptance tests.

**About the stubbing?**

Its kind of difficult to discuss this without concrete examples. All i can say right now is - just write the code one test at a time. If you do so, there are chances you wont encounter a situation where you have a complicated class and think about how to stub around its complex dependencies.

**What tests should be included in the build?**

Id say - all of them, if it is possible!

Comment: After we completed the test-code-refactor process; at the end, we will have a series of test (TDD test) that verify only small unit of code for that whole class. But should we not test the whole control flow from entry point to exit point? What is your thoughts?
In that sense, I tend to agree with @Jonathan Leffler that the TDD tests we write only serve to structure how our code will be. But to really assert whether those bits of code works well together, we need to have additional tests in the form of integration test?

Comment: In my understanding, integration tests are separate from unit tests and i agree they arent made during typical TDD, they have to be written separately, and they can be useful. Theyre exactly for the reason you mention: to check if those bits of code work **together**. Unit tests are for checking whether that code can work properly on its own :) Notice, that in my answer I wrote "I dont do any other **unit** tests" :)

Comment: Although, as mentioned by Carl, that TDD is a design methodology. The end product is that we will have a refactored code, with a series of "unit test" and any further change in one case can be checked for regression based on those "unit test" we wrote in the TDD process?

Comment: TDD is more than just unit testing. It includes the very important step of *refactoring* the code after passing the tests, and also applies to the creation of integration/acceptance tests. TDD itself doesn't require the creation of true unit tests; that is only one of three approaches for test development as described by Kent Beck, something like "fake it till you make it".

Answer (score 2):

TDD is about *design* during the 5 minutes or so of your original Red-Green-Refactor loop. But it's arguably about *testing* forever after since there is nothing left to design - your TDD tests then become part of a perfect test harness to detect regressions caused by further developments. So yes, I guess you could say test driven development is a form of unit testing :)

> But how are we suppose to know about the stubbing required when we are
>   writing our test first?

TDD often requires a (quick) prior modelling session where you flesh out the big picture classes your SUT will collaborate with.

However you need not go into the details of how these collaborators work. With mocks you basically apply wishful thinking that their implementations will behave correctly when you have TDD'd them at some point later, so for now you can just concentrate on the SUT.

> When you are building your application prior release, what kind of
>   test do you include in the build? Does the build run your integration
>   test or does it run only your unit test?

When you practice Continuous Integration, your unit tests are supposed to be run each time so you can theoretically take any (non-failed) build and use it as a release build.

However, you may want to run automated or manual integration/acceptance tests as well before releasing your version. GUIs for instance, are usually not easily unit testable so acceptance/integration testing is a good way to track bugs in them.

Comment: Are you trying to say not to TDD'd the part where our code will eventually invoke dependencies. Because as I mention in the question, when I'll break down my requirement into cases, some cases will consume dependency but given I have no method signature of those dependency call, how to I TDD them?

Comment: No, I'm not saying you shouldn't unit test the collaboration between your class and its dependencies. Indeed, mocks precisely allow you to do that. The signature of methods on these dependencies can be roughed out during the modelling phase I mentioned, or directly as you code your TDD test.